# Print all content in ScrollViewer - Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am showing some 100s of records in ScrollViewer Control. When I print the ScrollViewer Control it prints only the current view (10 records). How can I print all the 100s of data at once?

Comment: Check This solution in printing [link](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/05/09/creating-a-simple-report-writer-in-silverlight-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use PrintDocument class in Silverlight.
The usage is like..

in XAML file create List as

```
 <ScrollViewer Height="300" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl x:Name="printSurface">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Height="25">
                            <TextBlock Width="100"
                     Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <TextBlock Width="75"
                     Text="{Binding Genre.Name}" />
                            <TextBlock Width="50"
                     Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat=c}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

And Code behind looks like.

```
void printButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
  doc.PrintPage += new EventHandler<PrintPageEventArgs>(doc_PrintPage);
  doc.Print("Page title");
}

void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  // Stretch to the size of the printed page
  printSurface.Width = e.PrintableArea.Width;
  printSurface.Height = e.PrintableArea.Height;

  // Assign the XAML element to be printed
  e.PageVisual = printSurface;

  // Specify whether to call again for another page
  e.HasMorePages = false;
}
```